# Error.MysqlData.MysqlClient.MysqlExecption

Tags: mysql

I am having the following problem since from a winform application I am trying to connect to my DATABASE and it gives me the following error

---------------- ErrorMysql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException host: my ip is blocked because of many connection error; unblock whith 'mysqladmin flus-hosts'--------

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:-

1. **Verify the connection**. Check the network connection to make sure that there’s no TCP/IP connectivity issue from your host
2. **Increase the value of `max_connect_errors`**. You should find the setting in the MySQL configuration file under the `[mysqld]` tag (**my.ini** on Windows, **my.cnf** on Unix/Linux) and edit the value of max_connect_errors.

For example:

```
[mysqld]
max_connect_errors=10000;
```

Or run this query:

```
SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
```

3. **Flush host cache**. If you have shell access to the server, login and execute this command:

   mysql -u root -p -e 'flush hosts'

From the SQL console, run this statement:

```
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

If all those methods didn’t work, try restarting the server. It should clear the host cache too.

Comment: Anything wrong in this solution or is it not helping?